# Wamp is Green and Online but still 403 error

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

`C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9:`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:\wamp\wwww\sk\public
    ServerName sk.localhost
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

  <Directory "C:\wamp\wwww\sk\public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require local
    Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:\wamp\wwww\sk\public
    ServerName sk.localhost
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
  <Directory "C:\wamp\wwww\sk\public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require local
    Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Hosts file:**

```
    # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    #   127.0.0.1       localhost
    #   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       sk.localhost
```

When I try to access `localhost` or `sk.localhost` it gives me `403 error` (Wamp is green and Online. Anyone can help please? I don`t know what am I doing wrong here. I tried several methods from Internet but with no luck. Any help would be much appreciated. Best regards, Bogdan.

PHPMyadmin is working.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are using 2 different versions of the access security syntax and Apache is getting confused.

Change your Virtual Host definitions as below to use just the Apache 2.4 syntax and not the Apache 2.2 ones.

Also you should create a VH for localhost as well, as when you implement Virtual Hosts, Apache ignores the definition of localhost in the httpd.conf file.

```
# Should be the first VHOST definition so that it is the default virtual host
# Also access rights should remain restricted to the local PC 
# So that any random ip address attack will recieve an error code and not gain access
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:\wamp\wwww\sk\public
    ServerName sk.localhost
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

  <Directory "C:\wamp\wwww\sk\public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:\wamp\wwww\sk\public
    ServerName sk.localhost
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
  <Directory "C:\wamp\wwww\sk\public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The `Require local` tells Apache to only allow access to a VH domain if the client is on the PC running WampServer(Apache).

If you actually want to allow access from say another PC on your local network, you can add a line like this to the domain you want to access

```
Require local
Require ip 192.168.1
```

Or if you want to allow access from anwhere replace those lines with

```
Require all granted
```

***WARNING*** Dont allow access to the universe unless you really know what you are doing.

PS The WAMPserver Online/Offline feature only controls access and does not mean APache is running or not. Also once you implement Virtual Hosts it no longer has any relevance and shoudl be set OFFLINE as access control is now held in each individual Virtual Host.